# code writing optimisation

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class person, with id, name, salary properties.

```
class person
    friend id as long
    friend name as string
    friend salary as decimal
end class
```

I wan't to make a list of salaries.

```
Dim pList as new list(of person)
```

pList is loaded with 50 entries

```
Dim SalaryList as new list(of decimal)
for each p as person in plist
    SalaryList.add(p.salary)
next
```

Ok, this works.
But is there a way to do it like this :

```
Dim SalaryList as list(of decimal) = pList(each).salary
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to optimize?

Comment: to "code gray" : maybe you should read it entirely. The last question is how to make it in a single line instead of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) projection:

```
Dim SalaryList = pList.Select(Function(p) p.salary).ToList()
```

or

```
Dim SalaryList = From p in pList
                 Select p.salary
```

Note that the later just returns a query (`IEnumerable(Of Decimal)`) and not a `List`. If you really need a `List`, call [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the query, but often it is not necessary.

Comment: Interesting answer, but interface for Select is not implemented on plist (.net 3.5) and i can't use linq

Comment: Why can't you use Linq? It's part of .Net 3.5, so there's no reason not to use it. To use the `Select`-Method, you need to have a reference to `System.Core` and import the `System.Linq` namespace. Otherwise, there's not way to put your code into a single line.

Comment: I've always seen linq as a loss of performance, but you convinced me. I'll test it.

Comment: @cyrianox - Have you taken measurements that show that code written using LINQ has consistent performance issues?